# for loop , trying to print all element with index

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
why following code is giving the error
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-31d3f85500ea> in <module>
      1 name = "Shyam"
      2 for x in name:
----> 3     print(x,"th position elements are : ", name[x])

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

code :

```
name = "Shyam"
for x in name:
    print(x,"th position elements are : ", name[x])
```

Comment: please start from basics, and see how a for loop in python actually works

Comment: just change to: for x in range(len(name))

Comment: What do you think the value of `x` will be on the first iteration? Have you considered that it might be `'n'`? What do you think happens when you evaluate `name['n']`?

Answer (score 1):

`x` is a character from `name`, you can't use it as index. To get the caracters and their index simultaneously use `enumerate`

```
name = "Shyam"
for i, x in enumerate(name):
    print(i, "th position elements are : ", x)
```

This will print

```
0 th position elements are :  S
1 th position elements are :  h
2 th position elements are :  y
3 th position elements are :  a
4 th position elements are :  m
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below will work. the variable name is not a number. In a for loop it needs a number to iterate through.

```
name = "Shyam"
for x in range(len(name)):
    print(x, "The Character at %d Position = %c" %(x, name[x]))
```

Answer (score 0):

*x* is a character from the string *name*

So, in the first iteration of your loop you can assert that *x == 'S'*

This leads (effectively) to this expression:

*name['S']*

Given that *name* is a string, this will induce the error you're seeing

Answer (score 0):

**x** will not be an integer the way you have defined it, and that is why you are getting an error because as the error explicitly says **string indices must be integers**.

The code should be corrected as below:

```
name = "Shyam"
for x in range(len(name)):
    print(x,"th position elements are : ", name[x])
```

and the output will be:

```
0 th position elements are :  S
1 th position elements are :  h
2 th position elements are :  y
3 th position elements are :  a
4 th position elements are :  m
```